# Sonicwall: Is it a manufacturer tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

As part of the ongoing manufacturer tag clean up I came across this question:

[L2PT VPN ports are not opening](https://superuser.com/questions/1151589/l2pt-vpn-ports-are-not-opening)

Which is tagged with [sonicwall](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sonicwall), I was wondering if this is considered a manufacturer or is it now a brand under the Dell overlords.

Comment: Something I'd wonder is if the tags have value - is there anything unique about the sonicwall's firmware and the commands that you'd use that make the tag useful

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the hardware to make an assessment, I've only used the devices in passing.

Comment: They make a range of products, so I agree it's a manufacturer meta tag.  I don't see a benefit to creating dedicated, brand-specific tags for their individual products.  Any uniqueness can be handled by mentioning the model or brand in the question.

Comment: @fixer1234 but tags make criteria matching much easier, such as excel, excel-2013 etc. This is more of a discussion for SE meta though really as this type of thing could have a larger impact.

Comment: @Shawn, you're right, and that's the question here.  Are Sonicwall products substantively different from other brands in ways for which answers would be totally different?  If so, dedicated product tags can be useful.  If not, those tags can hinder getting an answer because some people may assume that a dedicated tag implies that there's a difference, so they're hesitant to suggest generic solutions that actually would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll post an answer to bump this so it can get some attention or disposition.

Even if Sonicwall is now part of Dell, it's still just a brand label, not a specific product.  So I don't see a question as to whether it's a manufacturer tag.  The question would be whether or not to create brand-specific replacement tags for the various products in the questions.

It would be great if subject matter experts weigh in on whether Sonicwall products are unique in a way that makes a difference for tagging purposes.  Even better would be if people familiar with the products do the honors of cleaning up these tags based on their own knowledge.

However, that's the cleanup.  I don't see a reason for not adding this tag to the list.  People can always delay cleanup until there is more feedback here on the best way to do it.  It isn't like we're running out of tags and questions to clean up.